Excel: VLOOKUP not working as expected, returns wrong values
Update:
A bit more clear what I am looking for. I want to have two different outputs.

If item from Table1 (large) in column 2 is available in Table2 (small) column 2, then print info from column 1 in Table2
If item from Table1 (large) in column 2 is available in Table2 (small) column 2, show Yes, otherwise show No.

----------------------
For some reason VLOOKUP or some variance in that function is not working. I made a randomized list to emulate my situation. I have a large list and I want to check if that item is available in a shorter list. I have a situation I just want to check if it is available. Or in another situation, if availble, show the text from the same row of column x. This last one I did not include in this example because it also does not work. Would be appreciated if I could get help with that code as well.
All tables are in Sheet1 except the short table is in Sheet2.
Large table: (Table1, in sheet1 -> Yellow is what is in Table2)




Name1
Name2
Info1
Info2




20412
132
Green
Apple


75557
100
Red
Water


84242
229
Pink
Apple


35828
407
Red
Egg


49052
931
Blue
Egg


82247
657
Pink
Water


12840
291
Blue
Water


10117
649
Pink
Egg


71444
298
Green
Water


30180
912
Pink
Water


12189
270
Green
Water


15267
239
Blue
Water


25988
475
Blue
Egg


96528
120
Blue
Apple


41453
776
Red
Beer


63700
895
Red
Water


50723
366
Red
Apple


78113
681
Blue
Beer


28698
846
Green
Water


37998
484
Green
Beer


32781
337
Green
Beer


68340
593
Blue
Water


46335
921
Red
Egg


55532
389
Pink
Water


87567
723
Green
Water


15967
704
Blue
Beer


24392
766
Green
Apple


87966
431
Blue
Apple


48426
981
Pink
Apple



Short Table: (Table2, in sheet2)




Name1_available
Name2_available




75557
229


49052
407


71444
298


30180
270


15267
475


63700
895


15967
681


87966
593



When I use VLOOKUP it seems like the first row is working, the second is not. In my real files I often notice both are not working. Does this have to do with it is not able to look to the left or in previous sheets?
The formulas used: (in Sheet1)
First column: =VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name1];Table2;1;FALSE)
Second column: =VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name2];Table2;2;FALSE)

I (manually) marked the correct values green and the wrong red. The second column does have green but is of course not working.

And when I want to look it up and place a YES or NO is there is a match, is also not working as it should: (again manually marked green and red)
First column: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name1];Table2[@[Name1_available]];1;FALSE));"No";"Yes")
Second column: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name2];Table2[@[Name2_available]];1;FALSE));"No";"Yes")


Why is it not working as I think it should work. I think I read somewhere that it cannot look backwards (columns or sheets earlier) Is that true? Why? Is there an alternative that does work in the whole excel file?

=VLOOKUP() will search in the first column only, the rest of the array is to determine what you want to return as output. So =VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name2];Table2;2;FALSE) would need to be =VLOOKUP(Table1[@Name2];Table2[Name2_available];1;FALSE). It seems like you're mixing up the @ in your error formulas.

I see, I don't understand how I made this mistake as it is clearly explained online. What should I use if I want to look it up in column 2 and for example print the information from column 4?

Would be better to use XLOOKUP if you're on 365.  Something like =XLOOKUP("b",Sheet1!$E$2:$E$4,Sheet2!$O$11:$O$13) would search for the letter "b" in Sheet1 and return the value from Sheet2 - if it's found on the second row in E2:E4 it would return the value from the second row in O11:013.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Is it possible to make it more dynamic? It is used in a "living" document. So people will add information and to prevent breakage in code it would be better to have it directed to a name. So if I edit your example to this, will that work? (can't test it right now): =XLOOKUP( Table1[@Name2];Sheet2!Table2[Name2_available];Sheet2!Table2[Name1_available]

Yes, that looks like it should work - both the lookup_array and return_array are in the same table so will be the same length so shouldn't be any problems there.

Here's a visual of what's happening with  =VLOOKUP(Table2[@Name1_available];Table1;3;FALSE) (applied in "Kolom1" of the second table.)
The [@Name1_available] refers to the cell left of your formula (in Table2 in this case), it's the value that's going to be looked up.
The lookup array is Table1, but it's actually only going to look in the first column [Name1], the return array is determined by 3, which in this case is [Info1]. So here Red is returned.
If you forget the @ in your first argument, you will generate a SPILL error, if you add the @ in the second argument, you will only look at 1 value in the lookup array.


Also: if you want to return a result that's left of your lookup column, you could use INDEX/MATCH combination.

Second also: using =XLOOKUP() requires to specify a lookup column (or row), and using it outside of your table can return multiple rows.
